# Google Charts API - Grouping a table for a LineGraph

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I currently have a table that looks like the following, and I'm trying to figure out how to create a line graph where the x-axis is 'Date', the y-axis is '# of API Calls' and there are three lines, one for each unique value in 'Category'. I've been pouring through the Google Charts API documentation but just can't seem to find the right combination of functions to make this work. Any help is appreciated.

[image: A DataTable]

Answer (score 0):

You need to arrange your data in an array in this format:

[
 ["date", "product", "recipe", "both"],
 ["Jan 1, 2012", 176, 0, 144],
 ["Jul 1, 2012", 16, 0, 82],
 ...
]

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ["date", "product", "recipe", "both"],
         ["Jan 1, 2012", 176, 0, 144],
         ["Jul 1, 2012", 16, 0, 82],
         ["Aug 1, 2012", 41, 81, 82],
         ["Sep 1, 2012", 27, 7, 7],
         ["Oct 1, 2012", 9, 0, 0]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Your data'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Here it is working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thnqa/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have been more specific in my original post. For certain sets of data I also have columns for things like 'domain' and 'registered vs non-registered'. Just wondering if there were any potential helper functions provided by Google for re-grouping by a particular column.

Comment: ah, right. I see. I'm not sure if there's anything straight out the box that can do this but you could certainly do it using something like the underscore.js groupBy method: http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy